# Все что внутри блока с "position: fixed (или absolute)" не нуждается в clearfix?

Tags: css

1. Почему не произошло "схлопывание" родителя в примере-1?
2. Каким образом родитель подстроился под float-контейнера, ведь они вырваны из потока?
3. Исходя из этого, можно сделать вывод, что ClearFix не нужен в тех контейнерах, где установлены `position:fixed` & `position:absolute`?

```css
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.fixed {
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.static {
  position: static;
  margin: 60px -8px;
}
.float-left {
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}
.float-right {
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Пример 1 Fixed -->>
<div class="container fixed">
  <div class="float-left">1</div>
  <div class="float-right"></div>
</div>

<!-- Пример 2 Static -->>
<div class="container static">
  <div class="float-left">2</div>
  <div class="float-right"></div>
</div>

<!-- Пример 3 Static + ClearFix -->
<div class="container static cf">
  <div class="float-left">3</div>
  <div class="float-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому-что создается блочный контекст форматирования, о котором можно почитать [здесь](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) или [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Здесь перечислено, что его создает:

**9.4.1 Block formatting contexts**

> **Floats**, **absolutely positioned** elements, block containers (such as **inline-blocks**, **table-cells**, and **table-captions**) that
>   are not block boxes, and **block boxes with 'overflow' other than
>   'visible'**(except when that value has been propagated to the
>   viewport) **establish new block formatting contexts for their
>   contents**.

Блочный контекст форматирования может быть создан посредством:

1. корневого элемента или чего-то, что содержит его
2. поплавками (элементы, у которых float не равно none)
3. **абсолютно позиционированными элементами** (элементами, значение 
   position которых либо **absolute**, либо **fixed**)
4. inline-blocks (элементы с display: inline-block)
5. ячейки таблицы (элементы с display: table-cell, установленным по
   умолчанию для ячеек таблицы)
6. заголовки таблицы (элементы с display: table-caption, установленным
   по умолчанию для заголовков таблицы)
7. элементы, у которых значение свойства overflow отличается от visible
8. flex блоки(элементы с display: flex или inline-flex)

Смотрим дальше [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height).

Конкретно строка описывает поведение такого элемента, если в нем лежит плавающий элемент:

**10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots**

> **In addition, if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then
>   the height is increased to include those edges**. Only floats that
>   participate in this block formatting context are taken into account,
>   e.g., floats inside absolutely positioned descendants or other floats
>   are not.

Если такой элемент содержит плавающие потомки, высота которых больше родителя, то родитель увеличится, чтобы обернуть их. Поэтому очистка обтекания не нужна.